# selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.webelement (session= element= )

Tags: python, selenium

Помогите получить "href" из :

```
<div id="div1" class="col-sm-1" style="padding-left: 0px; min-width: 65px; padding-right: 30px;">
<figure class="task-avatar">
<a class="avatar do-task" href="https://vk.com/photo737818736_457239024" target="_blank">
<img class="task-ava" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=&quot;/dist/img/no-avatar.gif&quot;;" src="https://sun9-north.userapi.com/sun9-78/s/v1/ig2/nmoo9nut2T4PndF3NgKm9zj9Q1jGHqOy9eJo3H_csl0Z6QFwUxtW5uAefJmEekIPggYuqa2omStZ76SDaei6Lurp.jpg?size=100x100&amp;quality=95&amp;crop=0,0,564,564&amp;ava=1" alt="">
</a>
</figure>
    </div>
```

Делаю так ничего не выходит.

```
users_url = []
for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="div1"]'):
    e = element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"task-avatar")
    users_url.append(e.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href'))
print(users_url)
```

Comment: В e.find_element By.CLASS_NAME Нужно было поменять на By.CSS_SELECTOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сразу искать тег `<a>`через class. Так как там два класса через пробел, то вместо пробела ставим точку.

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.avatar.do-task")
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Если нужных тегов `<a>` много на странице, то так

```
elems = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
         EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.avatar.do-task")))
print(elems[0].get_attribute("href"))
```